# Get text and put in attribute value

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get the text from between the "p" tags and put it in the title value.

before:

```
<option title="" value="Put Text">Put Text</option>
```

after:

```
<option title="$1,179.83" value="Put Text">Put Text</option>
```

Anyone know a javascript that can accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Get text and put in attribute value</title>
</head>

<body>


<div class="Text">
 <p>$1,179.83</p>
</div>


<form action="">

  <fieldset>

    <select class="putText" name="put-Text">
      <option title="" value="Put Text">Put Text</option>
    </select>

  </fieldset>

</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

****************************************************** UPDATE 2011-09-13 ******************************************************

Code is working now. The code also works for ie6-8:

[GET TEXT AND PUT IN ATTRIBUTE VALUE](http://jsfiddle.net/EFLym)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work in all browsers from IE4+ and NS7+

For newer browsers the [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByClassName) is built in

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/sXZth/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var pTag = document.getElementsByClassName("Text")[0].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
  var amount = pTag.innerHTML; 
 // not sure title is useful on option in all browsers
  document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].title=amount;
}
```

---

Extra code for older browsers

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName)
  document.getElementsByClassName=function (oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
/*
Written by Jonathan Snook, http://www.snook.ca/jonathan
Add-ons by Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com
*/        
var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && oElm.all)? oElm.all : oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
var arrReturnElements = new Array();
strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\\-");
var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strClassName + "(\\s|$)");
var oElement;
for(var i=0; i<arrElements.length; i++){
    oElement = arrElements[i];
    if(oRegExp.test(oElement.className)){
        arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
    }
}
return (arrReturnElements)
```

}

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you for the prompt and thorough answer @mplungjan

Comment: Just tested it in ie6, ie7 and ie8. I get an error at "var arrElements..." And when I remove the extra code for older browsers I get an error at "var pTag...". Error says: "Object doesn't support this property or method". In Firefox the code worked just fine, how can this be fixed for ie6, ie7 and ie8?

Comment: I found a solution, replace getElementsByClassName by getElementById and replace title="" by id="putTextOption". Working now: http://jsfiddle.net/EFLym/

Answer (score 1):

add an ID to option

```
<option id="an_option" title="" value="Put Text">Put Text</option>
```

or get it like this

```
var an_option = document.getElementsByClass("putText")[0].getElementsByName("option")[0];
```

$1,179.83 is saved in

```
var vall = document.getElementsByClass("Text")[0].getElementsByName("p")[0].textValue;
```

set an title via

```
document.getElementById("an_option").title = vall;
// or
an_option.title = vall;
```

**But note that addressing by classes is vague, and can be easily mistaken**
It is always better to use an ID if you need to address it properly (read difference between ID and CLASS attribute)

Comment: You mean like this? 


<form action="">
  
  <fieldset>
  
    <select class="putText" name="put-Text">
      <option title="" id="an_option" value="Put Text">Put Text</option>
    </select>
    
  </fieldset>
  
</form> 


<script>
window.onload = function() {
 
  var vall = document.getElementsByClass("Text")[0].getElementsByName("p")[0].textValue;
  
  document.getElementById("an_option").title = vall;

};
</script>


Doesn't seem to work, though I could be doing something wrong.

Comment: please do a pastebin or jsfiddle from your comment, and then post link to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. Using jQuery it's quiet simple:

```
$('.putText').attr('title', $('.Text p').text());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Preferable no jQuery, cause it interferes with my other scripts.